# Using VS2017 and VS2015 C# projects in the same location, side-by-side

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Is anyone out there using Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 .CSPROJ files alongside each other in the same folder?   Are there any other incompatibilites, besides the solution and project files that I should worry about?

Basically what I want to do is allow our developers to continue to use VS2015 and those projects -- just for a while -- while all still working on exact same set of same code files.  I don't want to move/change anything else.

I've already created all the new project files and solution file.  But 'm wondering if I can just put them in the same physical disk folder alongside each other and have everyone go merrily about their development tasks with either VS2015 or VS2017.

The duplication of work synchronizing the project files themselves is not a concern.  I just want to make sure there aren't any OTHER format differences that might cause some sort of build/run problem for me.

Is anyone else out out there doing this?  Is this workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 side by side without any issues. Our application ran on both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 before every developer migrated to VS 2017.

You do need to keep in mind few things though:

1. Visual Studio 2017 by supports C# 7.0. Make sure that you use same language version in both the IDEs.
2. VS 2017 also supports stuff like editor.config. I would suggest to avoid using it (though I feel it should not be an issue)
3. If you are using on .NET Core project without `csproj`. Do not think you would be able to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any incompatibility, but you should check when you are creating a new project in VS2017 the kind of project, you should have two things in mind, first, when you are creating .net projects, you have to keep using the old .net framework instead of .net core, and second (only if you are going to create desktop/libraries/console projects), you need to use the Common option instead the new option (check on the dropdown to select the .net framework version that allows you to select versions lower than 4.5), cause if not, then you have the incorrect kind of project selected and this kind of project doesn't work in VS2015 as they change the structure of the .csproj file. Hope this little explanation helps you.

### Update

What I wanted to say with this explanation is that every projects that comes from VS2015 or 2017 if they have the same structure (same old kind of .net framework), then you can do what you want to do, but if for some reason you need to make a .net core, then this will not work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that VS2017 supports C# language version features that 2015 does not. If anyone uses those features you will not be able to build the projects in VS 2015.

You can enforce language version in the .csproj files but this is done per BuildConfiguration and can be tedious to configure for larger solutions with many projects.

To make the changes

- Right click the Project and select Properties
- Then Build Then
- Advanced (Bottom Right corner) General > Language Version
- Change to C#6.0

Overall it is possible but you may need to retain VS2015 if you have any SSIS or SSRS packages as the tooling is still not available for general release (Oct 17) and is still in preview.

Comment: You can avoid the language version issue by using the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package (which is up to at least c#7)